# Existence of $k$th moment doesn't imply existence of absolute $k$th moment but what about the expected value?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, expected-value, absolute-convergence

I know and I am able to prove (from the theory of Lebesgue integral) that, given a random variable $X$ and for a generic $k=0,1,2,3,\dots$, it **is true** that
$$\mathbb{E}(|X|^k)<\infty\,\Rightarrow \mathbb{E}(X^k)<\infty$$
(and also $\mathbb{E}(X^r)<\infty$ for every moment of order $r<k$).

On the contrary I know that **isn't true** that
$$\mathbb{E}(X^k)<\infty\,\Rightarrow \mathbb{E}(|X|^k)<\infty$$
and I am able to show it with some counterexamples.

On the other hand, I know and I am able to prove that for a very important case - $k=1$, the moment of order 1 AKA *the expected value* - it **is true** that $\mathbb{E}(X)$ exists finite **if and only if** $\mathbb{E}(|X|)<\infty$:
$$\mathbb{E}(X)<\infty\,\iff \mathbb{E}(|X|)<\infty$$

Is this "double implication" (*if and only if* instead of *if*) an exception only true for the 1st moment? If so, why is that and/or where am I reasoning wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: There are examples with $EX=-\infty$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How does it relate do the single/double implication between existence of moments and absolute moments?

Comment: In the language of measure theory it is wrong to say that $EX <\infty$ iff $E|X| <\infty$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ok, thanks for the info! I still can't see if that, somehow, answers my question...

Answer (score 2):

A basic fact in measure theory says $\int |f| d\mu <\infty$ iff $\int f^{+} d\mu$ and $\int f^{-} d\mu$ are both finite which is true if and only if $\int f d\mu$ is well defined and its value is a real number (not $+\infty$ or $-\infty$). In this sense $EX^{k}$ is well defined and it is a real number if and only if $E|X|^{k} <\infty$ so the equivalence does hold for every positive integer $k$.

Answer (score 0):

If $k$ is odd, use $X_\text{new}=X_\text{old}^k$. If $k$ is even, $X^k=|X|^k$.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow on the odd-related part of the comment: if I define a new $X$ as you suggest, shouldn't it hold for it $\mathbb{E}(X_\text{new}) \iff \mathbb{E}(|X_\text{new}|)$ as it holds for $X_\text{old}\equiv X$? But, if so, it should also hold $\mathbb{E}(X^k) \iff \mathbb{E}(|X|^k)$, shouldn't it? And yet I know it doesn't! I can't see where I'm messing this up... :(

Comment: @luciadefinetti If your $k=1$ claim is right, $\Bbb E(X_\text{old}^k)$ exists and is finite iff $\Bbb E(X_\text{new})$ exists and is finite iff $\Bbb E(|X_\text{new}|)$ exists and is finite iff $\Bbb E(|X_\text{old}|^k)$ exists and is finite.

Comment: Exactly and yet it's not true. Existence of absolute moment of order k implies existence of moment of order k, the opposite is not true!

Comment: @luciadefinetti Maybe you should edit into your question the counterexamples you've alluded to.

Comment: I was alluding at the usual relation between convergence and absolute convergence. Something like the classical example of the convergence of $\sum_n (-1)^n \frac{1}{n}$ that, while convergent, is not absolutely convergent.